# How to insert x to the power something in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, symbols

I want to insert x^2 in Eclipse. Is it possible to insert x square symbol or just square symbol in Eclipse? I mean GUI symbol.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to achieve exactly? (update your question)

Comment: Also, please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: do you mean square symbol in GUI? please, make your question clear.

Comment: yes. I meant GUI symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to insert square(^) in editor

Normally we can insert the square(^) in two ways

1. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> or
2. Press Hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>(num keys)